# What are the valid possible value for "signDateFormat" account settings of DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign REST API to set "signDateFormat" value for the DocuSign Account. Below are the request json object which is used to update value of docusign account settings.

[image]

But it could not get update and we are getting below error

[image].

If i set value to "d/M/yyyy" or "M/d/yyyy" then value get updated successfully.

Anyone have an idea what are the valid values for this field and why its not taking the value "dd/MM/yyyy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the valid values for the signDateFormat for the [updateAccountSettings](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/updateSettings/) api

- d/M/yyyy
- dd-MM-yy
- dd-MMM-yy
- dd-MM-yyyy
- dd.MM.yyyy
- dd-MMM-yyyy
- dd MMMM yyyy
- M/d/yyyy
- MM-dd-yyyy
- MM/dd/yyyy
- MM/dd/yy
- MMM-dd-yyyy
- MMM d, yyyy
- MMMM d, yyyy
- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy-MMM-dd
- yyyy/MM/dd
- yyyy MMMM d

You can also see the list of valid Sign Date formats in the [DocuSign admin app](https://admindemo.docusign.com/signing-settings).

Documentation [Here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-signing-settings). See `Document Formatting` section